# How can i get multi checkboxes value in metbox wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, meta-boxes

I make list of check boxes by WordPress meta-box and i can not get this value in my theme.

i can get my text value with this code

```
<? echo get_post_meta($post->ID, $prefix . 'text', true); ?>
```

But if i use this code in check box it give me "Array"

This is my Full code

```
$prefix = 'dbt_';
$meta_box = array(
'id' => 'my-meta-box',
'title' => 'Product Information',
'page' => 'post',
'context' => 'normal',
'priority' => 'high',
'fields' => array(
array(
        'name' => 'Colors',
        'desc'  => '',
        'id'    => $prefix.'colors',
        'type'  => 'checkbox_group',
        'options' => array (
        'one' => array (
        'label' => 'Black',
        'value' => 'one'
    ),
        'two' => array (
        'label' => 'White',
        'value' => 'two'
    ),
        'three' => array (
        'label' => 'Red',
        'value' => 'three'
    ),

        'four' => array (
        'label' => 'Blue',
        'value' => 'four'
    ),

        'five' => array (
        'label' => 'Green',
        'value' => 'five'
    ),

        'six' => array (
        'label' => 'Yellow',
        'value' => 'six'
    ),

        'seven' => array (
        'label' => 'Brown',
        'value' => 'seven'
    )
)
)
)
);

  add_action('admin_menu', 'mytheme_add_box');
// Add meta box
function mytheme_add_box() {
global $meta_box;
add_meta_box($meta_box['id'], $meta_box['title'], 'mytheme_show_box', $meta_box['page'], $meta_box['context'], $meta_box['priority']);
}

    // Callback function to show fields in meta box
function mytheme_show_box() {
global $meta_box, $post;
// Use nonce for verification
echo '<input type="hidden" name="mytheme_meta_box_nonce" value="', wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__)), '" />';
echo '<table class="form-table">';
foreach ($meta_box['fields'] as $field) {
// get current post meta data
$meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['id'], true);
echo '<tr>',
'<th style="width:20%"><label for="', $field['id'], '">', $field['name'], '</label></th>',
'<td>';
switch ($field['type']) {
case 'checkbox_group':
foreach ($field['options'] as $option) {
    echo '<input type="checkbox" value="'.$option['value'].'" name="'.$field['id'].'[]" id="'.$option['value'].'"',$meta && in_array($option['value'], $meta) ? ' checked="checked"' : '',' />
            <label for="'.$option['value'].'">'.$option['label'].'</label><br />';
}
break;
}
echo '</td><td>',
'</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
}


add_action('save_post', 'mytheme_save_data');
// Save data from meta box
function mytheme_save_data($post_id) {
global $meta_box;
// verify nonce
if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['mytheme_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__))) {
return $post_id;
}
// check autosave
if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
return $post_id;
}
// check permissions
if ('page' == $_POST['post_type']) {
if (!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id)) {
return $post_id;
}
} elseif (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {
return $post_id;
}
foreach ($meta_box['fields'] as $field) {
$old = get_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], true);
$new = $_POST[$field['id']];
if ($new && $new != $old) {
update_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $new);
} elseif ('' == $new && $old) {
delete_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $old);
}
}
}
```

any body Can give me the correct full code to get my values because I`m trying to learn PHP language

It`s my first WordPress theme and i hope if i can finish it fast,

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This typically happens when you try to cast an array as a string. For example:

```
$data = array('one', 'two', 'three');
echo $data;
// will echo Array
```

Revisit your loop and how you're accessing it's values. Use something like print_r() or var_dump() to preview the data before using it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, But Is it possible to explain to me the correct way because I do not know too much about PHP

Answer (score 0):

Inside your array loop maybe adding a second loop would get you the array values you need.  Also, your code inside the loop at first glance looks like there could be some syntax errors

```
foreach ($field['options'] as $options) {
    foreach ($options as $option) {
    ...
    ...
    }
}
```

Not tested but here is an example

```
 foreach ($field['options'] as $options) {
    foreach ($options as $option) {              
        $checked = $meta && in_array($option['value'], $meta) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
        echo '<input type="checkbox" value="' . $option["value"] . '" name="' . $field["id"] . '[]" id="' . $option["value"] . ' ' . $checked . ' />';
        echo '<label for="' . $option["value"] . '">' . $option["label"] . '</label>';
        echo '<br />'; 
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, But can you give me the correct full loop to get my values in theme, This is my first WordPress theme and my first work with Meta-box and i`m really do not know too much about php :(

Comment: My code is work and save changes but my problem is How I View this values in my theme post page

Comment: Are you asking how to view the source at the page?

Comment: Once your at the page where you called for the checkbox option you can just right click on page and view source.